# Access of Non-Static Function of a Class in PHP

Tags: php, oop, class

Why is this legal in PHP?

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public function test() {
        echo "hello\n";
    }
}

Foo::test();
?>
```

test() is a non-static function but I can access it without an instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's because of backwards compatibility. In PHP4 you didn't have the static keyword for methods (still looking for reference, but so far this is all I've found https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). This way, PHP4 code can still run without a problem.

It is better practice to declare your static functions as such and if you turn on E_STRICT you'll see a notice about this.

`error_reporting(E\_ALL | E\_STRICT);`

**Update**: well, this is the best I've found http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34990 and http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47891.

Answer (score 6):

It's legal, but generally frowned upon, until you reference `$this` in your statically called method which will throw a fatal error.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Calling non-static methods statically
>   generates an E_STRICT level warning.

Answer (score 0):

This works because you have not enabled the [E_STRICT](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) error level. Once enabled PHP will stop letting you to do this.

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe that you can access a method of a class with out a instance of the object.